# javascript language specification for V8 engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

nodejs is base on v8 engine, I think something must be changed or deprecated for javascript language. Any documents or books ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Node.js's wiki page:

> Note that V8 implements all of ECMA 3rd edition and parts of the new stuff in the ECMA 5th edition

See: https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/ECMA-5-Mozilla-Features-Implemented-in-V8

Some of ES5's features that V8 implements are for example: Array methods like `map` and `forEach`, the new `Object` functions like `create` or `keys`, `String` methods like `trim()` as well as the ability to define getters and setters.

For a full list see the above link.

Answer (score 0):

From the [homepage for the project](http://code.google.com/p/v8/):

> V8 implements ECMAScript as specified in [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), 3rd edition, and runs on Windows XP and Vista, Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard), and Linux systems that use IA-32 or ARM processors.

You'll need to follow through to [the historical section](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262-arch.htm) to get 3rd edition today.

Comment: V8 says it implements the standard. It doesn't say it deviates from it. A quick note about the changes would be "There aren't any".